# JAX-WS and Embedded Jetty - Error when publishing Endpoint at the provided HttpContext

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jetty, jax-ws

We have a publish/subscribe WS application, on which we want to replace the existing Oracle’s Java HTTP Server implementation to an embedded Jetty one. Unfortunately, we are facing some troubles when we try to publish the web service, using the Endpoint.publish(HttpContext) call. As an additional information, that we are forced to use this call, we cannot use the Endpoint.publish(address) one.

I have just created a test application in order to isolate the problem and ask for your advice.

Please find below the TestService class:

```
public class TestService {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int port = 8081;
    String path = "/myservice";
    AsyncProvider<Source> internalProvider = new InternalProvider();
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(internalProvider);

   // Preparing the Service
    URL wsdlLocation = TestService.class.getResource("NotificationService.wsdl");
    Source source = null;
    try {
        source = new StreamSource(wsdlLocation.openStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't open WSDL", ex);
    }
    source.setSystemId(wsdlLocation.toExternalForm());
    List<Source> metadata = new ArrayList<Source>();
    metadata.add(source);
    endpoint.setMetadata(metadata);
    QName serviceName = new QName("http://notification/", "ConsumerService");
    QName portName = new QName("http://notification/", "ConsumerPort");
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(Endpoint.WSDL_SERVICE, serviceName);
    map.put(Endpoint.WSDL_PORT, portName);
    endpoint.setProperties(map);

    // This is the fragment of code that is replacing Oracle’s HTTP Server with Jetty
    Server s = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port));
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(s);
    connector.setReuseAddress(true);
    connector.setPort(port);
    s.setConnectors(new Connector[] {connector});
    s.setHandler(new ContextHandlerCollection());
    JettyHttpServer httpServer = new JettyHttpServer(s, false);
    JettyHttpContext context = (JettyHttpContext) httpServer.createContext(path); // It’s seems that is not taking into account the path
    endpoint.publish(context);        
    httpServer.start();

    W3CEndpointReference providerEPR = (W3CEndpointReference)endpoint.getEndpointReference(); // Throws a NullPointerException when calling HttpEndpoint.getEPRAddress()
    System.out.println("providerEPR: " + providerEPR);  

}

@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(value = javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.PAYLOAD)
private final static class InternalProvider implements AsyncProvider<Source>{

    @Override
    public void invoke(Source t, AsyncProviderCallback<Source> apc, WebServiceContext wsc) {
        processCall(t, apc, wsc);
    }

    private void processCall(Source t, AsyncProviderCallback<Source> apc, WebServiceContext wsc) {
        // Process the Request and generate a reply
         …

    }

}
```

And here attached the Consumer Client:

```
public class ConsumerClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Dispatch<Source> consumer;

    //Get the Service
    URL wsdURL = new URL("http://localhost:8081/myservice?wsdl");
    QName serviceName = new QName("http://notification/", "ConsumerService");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdURL, serviceName);

    //Get the Dispatch
    QName portName = new QName("http://notification/", "ConsumerPort");
    consumer = service.createDispatch(portName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);

    //ProducerService - Subscribe
    String message = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
            + "<not:subscribe xmlns:not=\"http://notification/\" xmlns:S=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"
            + "<name>Peter</name>"
            + "<epr> <Address xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\">http://localhost:8081/myservice</Address>"
            + "<Metadata xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\" xmlns:wsdli=\"http://www.w3.org/ns/wsdl-instance\" wsdli:wsdlLocation=\"http://notification/ http://localhost:8081/myservice?wsdl\">"
            + "<wsam:InterfaceName xmlns:wsam=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata\" xmlns:wsaw=\"http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl\" xmlns:wsns=\"http://notification/\">wsns:Consumer</wsam:InterfaceName>"
            + "<wsam:ServiceName xmlns:wsam=\"http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata\" xmlns:wsaw=\"http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl\" xmlns:wsns=\"http://notification/\" EndpointName=\"ConsumerPort\">wsns:ConsumerService</wsam:ServiceName>"
            + "</Metadata> </epr> </not:subscribe> ";

    System.out.println("[ConsumerClient] Sending Subscribe Message");

    Source res = consumer.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(message)));   // Here is where it crashes cause it cannot find the service (com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found)

    System.out.println("[ConsumerClient] Received Response:");

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    Result output = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(res, output);

}
```

I attach the logs we get below

On the server side

```
2016-05-03 17:14:24.374:INFO::main: Logging initialized @759ms
May 03, 2016 5:14:29 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase createRoot
INFO: Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: com.sun.metro:pp=/,type=WSEndpoint,name=ConsumerService-ConsumerPort
2016-05-03 17:14:30.317:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2016-05-03 17:14:30.437:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.h.s.HttpSpiContextHandler@557db906{/myservice,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-05-03 17:14:30.494:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@44e8195b{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2016-05-03 17:14:30.495:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6883ms
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.getEPRAddress(HttpEndpoint.java:104)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.getEndpointReference(HttpEndpoint.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getEndpointReference(EndpointImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.getEndpointReference(EndpointImpl.java:341)
at fr.endpoint.TestService.main(TestService.java:111)
```

On the client side

```
2016-05-03 17:14:39.518:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2297ms
[ConsumerClient] Sending Subscribe Message
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 404: Not Found
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:222)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:179)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:93)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:629)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:588)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:573)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:470)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:319)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.doInvoke(DispatchImpl.java:189)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:215)
at fr.endpoint.ConsumerClient.main(ConsumerClient.java:54)
```

What are we missing when setting the context for this Endpoint? Or maybe it’s because we don’t initialize correctly the Jetty HttpServer?

I wasn’t able to find a lot of documentation regarding the integration of JAX-WS and Jetty. We’ll really appreciate if you can give us any hint and advice.

We are using Metro 2.3 as JAX-WS RI , Jetty 9.2.15, Java 1.7 (jdk1.7.0_21) and Netbeans 8.0.2.

Thanks for your time

David

Answer (score 0):

You can  replace the existing Oracle’s Java HTTP Server implementation to an embedded Jetty by setting this property

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider", "org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");
```

Make sure you have added [jetty-http-spi jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http-spi) file on classpath

This code worked for me

```
    ContentWsImplement contentImplement = new ContentWsImplement();
    System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider", "org.eclipse.jetty.http.spi.JettyHttpServerProvider");
    Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8000/services/getcontent", contentImplement);
```

Replace *ContentWsImplement* with your web service implement